# Prove that $E(X+Y)^p \le 2^p (E(X^p)+E(Y^p))$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

Suppose $X, Y$ are nonnegative random variables and $p \ge 0$. How can I prove that

$E(X+Y)^p \le 2^p (E(X^p)+E(Y^p)).$

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: use inequality $(a+b)^p \le 2^p  (a^p+b^p)$ for $p\ge 0$.  But this something you can find in any standard book in probability. Did you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try using the two inequalities $X+Y\leq 2\max\{X,Y\}$ and $\max\{X,Y\}\leq X+Y$.